# Does anyone know invincibility cheat for game pipi and bibis?

Tags: arcade, mame

Can anyone help me out by telling me the invincibility cheat code for the game pipi and bibis in arcade game mame32?

If anyone knows, please help me out and also tell me how to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, arcade games don't have invincibility cheats, they are designed to let the owner make money, with an invincibility setting, a player could play hours with just one coin

Try with mame to use [Pugsy's memory cheats](http://cheat.retrogames.com/) who change the value of the player life in memory, or maybe in the "dip switch" settings of the game (for example some neo geo games had cheats in dip switch - an operator could decide to set it)